# How to create Vec<Vec<String>>?

Tags: rust

I like experimenting with Rust, but something doesn't always work for me, so as part of a new API project, I prepared a code that I thought would work.
I need to execute above code

```rust
let mut rows: Vec<Vec<&String>> = Vec::new();
{
let grade_string: String = String::from("Example Title");
let grade_category_string: String = String::from("Example Message");

let mut pos_row: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();
pos_row.push(&grade_string);
pos_row.push(&grade_category_string);

rows.push(pos_row);
}
```

And gets error

```
error[E0597]: `grade_string` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib/functions.rs:25:26
   |
21 |             let grade_string: String = String::from("Example Title");
   |                 ------------ binding `grade_string` declared here
...
25 |             pos_row.push(&grade_string);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
28 |             rows.push(pos_row);
   |             ---- borrow later used here
...
31 |         }
   |         - `grade_string` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `grade_category_string` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib/functions.rs:26:26
   |
22 |             let grade_category_string: String = String::from("Example Message");
   |                 --------------------- binding `grade_category_string` declared here
...
26 |             pos_row.push(&grade_category_string);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
27 |         
28 |             rows.push(pos_row);
   |             ---- borrow later used here
...
31 |         }
   |         - `grade_category_string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How can I execute the command without problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what's going on:

```rust
let mut rows: Vec<Vec<&String>> = Vec::new();
{
  // You are defining two strings.
  // Like every other data structure in Rust, these strings are created within 
  // a scope (delimited here by the curly braces).
  //
  // If you don't move (or perhaps copy) them out of the scope or wrap them
  // within a data structure that is going to be moved or copied out of the
  // scope, they'll be deallocated, their destructor is going to run, etc.
  let grade_string: String = String::from("Example Title");
  let grade_category_string: String = String::from("Example Message");

  // Here, you're informing Rust that you want a vector of _references_
  // to strings. References do not copy, do not move, they're just shortcuts
  // to things that are already in memory.
  let mut pos_row: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();

  // Here, you're adding references to your strings.
  // They're not keeping the string alive, just let you access them quickly.
  pos_row.push(&grade_string);
  pos_row.push(&grade_category_string);

  rows.push(pos_row);

  // We've reached the end of the scope. Everything that is bound to this
  // scope will now be deallocated. That's your two strings `grade_string`
  // and `grade_category_string`.
}
// At this point, if Rust accepted your code, `rows` would contain to
// references to strings that do not exist anymore. Using them would
// cause memory corruption (that's what would happen in most non-garbage
// collected languages).
```

In this case, we can fix the problem easily, by moving the `String`s out
of the scope. To do that, just don't tell Rust that you want a reference!

```rust
let mut rows: Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new(); // <- Removed the `&`.
{
  // Define two strings in the current scope.
  let grade_string: String = String::from("Example Title");
  let grade_category_string: String = String::from("Example Message");

  // Here, you're informing Rust that you want a vector of `String`.
  // This vector will also live only until the end of the scope.
  let mut pos_row: Vec<String> = Vec::new(); // <- Removed the `&`.

  // Move your strings into `pos_row`.
  pos_row.push(grade_string);          // <- Removed the `&`.
  pos_row.push(grade_category_string); // <- Removed the `&`.

  // At this point, `grade_string` and `grade_category_string` don't
  // exist anymore. You could check that by attempting to println
  // them, for instance: Rust won't let you because they've been moved.

  // Move `pos_row` into `rows`.
  rows.push(pos_row);

  // Similarly, at this point, `pos_row` doesn't exist anymore.

  // We've reached the end of the scope. Everything that is bound to this
  // scope will now be deallocated. As it turns out, there is nothing bound
  // to this scope, so nothing happens.
}
// At this point, `rows` is still alive and contains all the data you want!
```

As a side-note, you could write something slightly more compact:

```rust
let mut rows = vec![]; // Rust will infer the type.
{
  let pos_row = vec![  // Rust will infer the type.
      String::from("Example Title"),
      String::from("Example Message")      
  ]; // Note that `pos_row` is not declared `mut` since we never actually modify it anymore.

  rows.push(pos_row);
}
```

You could even factor this into a single statement if you wanted.

Comment: You can get even more compact: `vec![["Example Title", "Example Message"].into_iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect()]`